# jQuery getting jSon data but not returning/assigning value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am using jQuery to call a controller, the controller is returning a value.  the jQuery is getting the value however it is not setting it to my variable and returning it.  what am I doing wrong here?

GetDepartmentID is called with a value of 1.  It goes to the controler, the controller returns the departmentID which is 1.

console.log("Inside-DepartmentID " + data) in the console this shows 1 so I know the data is being returns from the controller.

I then assign data to departmentID.  Return it.  Then my outer function tries to console.log the return and it is undefined.  I don't get it.

The .change function calls the GetdepartmentID(1);

```
function GetDepartmentID(functionID) {
    var departmentID;
    jQuery.getJSON("/MasterList/GetDepartmentID/" + functionID, null, function (data) {
        console.log("Inside-DepartmentID " + data)
        departmentID = data;
    });
    return departmentID;
}

jQuery('#functionID').change(function () {
        var functionID = jQuery(this);
        //console.log(functionID.val());
        var value = GetDepartmentID(functionID.val());
        console.log("test " + value);
        //GetOwnerList(value);
    });
```

Comment: Felt this was better as a comment: AJAX is asynchronous, your request is still processing when you hit the `console.log` statement, therefore returning `undefined`

Comment: @tymeJV does that mean what I am trying to do is not possible?  All I need to do is pass my controller an int, it returns an int and then I use that int for another AJAX call.

Comment: @JamesWilson One not so good way to do this would be to make your Ajax call `async:false` switching from $.getJSON to traditional ajax call...

Comment: @James Wilson -- Of course it's possible, see PSL's answer, you need a callback function.

Comment: @tereško you need to be more careful about globally editing tags, this question has absolutely nothing to do with asp.net mvc, nor do I see any implication in any answers or comments about it.

Comment: Again, @MystereMan, the topic has nothing to do with MVC in general, which means that user meant ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: @tereško - No, it does not mean that.  There's no indication that it has anything to do with asp.net-mvc, it could be php mvc, or java struts, or any number of other mvc based technologies.

Comment: @MystereMan, `"/MasterList/GetDepartmentID/"` are ASP-style routes. And users history indicated that he's and ASP user. When tagging "mvc" the user definitely meant a framework.  If you want to educate your fellow developers, that just because you use a framework does not meant the question has anthing to do with it, that's your problem.

Comment: @tereško - That doesn't mean it *IS* asp.net-mvc, you're just jumping to conclusions.  In another one you tagged, they were talking about JDBC (java).  I'm suggesting that you do not jump to conclusions, and simply leave it as is.  If there's nothing relating to MVC, remove any mvc tags, don't just retag it to something else equally irrelevant.

Comment: Look at the users profile. I did not jump to the conclusions.

Comment: @tereško - it's irrelevant what their profile says.  Just because someone typically posts about one thing doesn't mean they can't be posting about another thing.  If the post itself does not give the indication, you are jumping to a conclusion.

Comment: How about you stop trolling and ask the OP?!

Comment: Because to ME it looks clear that he meant to tag it with "asp.net-mvc".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way to process the data returned back from AJAX call.

```
function processResults(departmentID)
{
   console.log("test " + departmentID);
   GetOwnerList(departmentID);
   // Someother code.
}

function GetDepartmentID(functionID, callBack) {

    jQuery.getJSON("/MasterList/GetDepartmentID/" + functionID, null, function (data) {
        console.log("Inside-DepartmentID " + data)
        callBack(data); //Invoke the callBackhandler with the data
    });

}

jQuery(function(){
jQuery('#functionID').change(function () {
        var functionID = jQuery(this);
        //console.log(functionID.val());
        GetDepartmentID(functionID.val(), processResults); // pass function as reference to be called back on ajax success.
    });
 });
```

Or just do this way: This is as good as putting all your subsequent processing code inside your getJSON handler.

```
   function processResults(data)
    {
       //handle the data here.
    }

  function GetDepartmentID(functionID) {
    jQuery.getJSON("/MasterList/GetDepartmentID/" + functionID, null, processResults);
  }



jQuery(function(){
    jQuery('#functionID').change(function () {
            var functionID = jQuery(this);
            //console.log(functionID.val());
            GetDepartmentID(functionID.val()); // pass function as reference to be called back on ajax success.
        });
     });
```

Comment: Thanks PSL is one way better than the other, or is it just preference?

Comment: If you specifically want to process the data before passing it to the function(which might be generic and used elsewhere)  go with the first one. else you can just go with second approach...

Comment: Yeah, had to wait 7 minutes tho. :)